# Can I declare new class if I require few fields from existing class

Tags: c#, oop

Consider I have class `ProductDetails` contains almost 20 properties

```
public class ProductDetails  
{  
    public int ProductId{get;set;}
    public string ProductName{get;set;}
    public int Price{get;set;}
    public string ManufactureName{get;set;}
    public string BatchNo{get;set;}
    public string Brand{get;set;}  
    .  
    .  
 }
```

I am getting all details of product and are mapped to the class properties.

But in my synario we are updating only few property values of product like price only.

Is it good practice that I have to use same class and assign value to ProductId and Price or I have to create another class `UpdateProductDetails` to send class object to update method for updating product details in DB.

```
public class UpdateProductDetails{  
        public int ProductId{get;set;}
        public int Price{get;set;}
}
```

Request to suggest me best practice in such synario in terms of code standard and memory usage.

Comment: Recommendations are kind of off-topic if you do not clearly describe your needs (from a technical View). Please be much more detailed, unless nobody can (and is Not willing to) help you. Also SO is not a code writing Service.

Comment: You could create, for instance, `BaseProductDetails` which would contain properties for updating and `ProductDetails`, inheriting from `BaseProductDetails`.

Comment: Hey Johney, that would be better idea

Answer (score 0):

If the values are too less then you can send it as a parameter.

```
void updatePrice(int Price)
{
      //your code goes here
}
```

If you have many update functions then creating seperate class is not a good idea.

In that you can use like this.

```
void updateProductDetails(ProductDetails p)
{
      if(p.ProductId!=null)
      {
          this.ProductId=p.ProductId;
      }
      //rest of the code goes here
}
```

if you have only one or two updates you also may can consider createing new class

Answer (score 0):

Almost 20 properties seems like a awfull lot for one class. Could it be that maybe there is too much functionality in taht one class, and you should have more then one class to begin with? Of course that class you showed also looks like a in-Programm representation of a Database, wich would mean the database dictates the classes.

The big question is: Why a extra class? What is it's purpose, that just handing in the existing class to the code and setting the values does not solve? If you just need a custom type (for return values, parameters, logging, etc.) a struct can often be the better alternative. It is much more leightweight for holding a few variables that do not need any logic.. If even a custom struct is too much work and a simple list/array can not handle the job, there is the class [Tupel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx).

My usual order is: set the types you have directly > hand them down to your custom code > array to hold values > tupel to hold values > custom struct to hold values > custom class to hold values (if you also need custom logic).